# Is there a keybinding to focus an already-open search editor in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to use the recently-added Search Editor functionality as my primary method of searching across files. I set my keybinding for `search.action.openNewEditor` to "shift+command+f" to override the default search, and that works great. But if I enter that keybinding again, it opens a new Search Editor. What I want it to do is open the Search Editor on the first press, and if the Search Editor is already open but not focused -- for example, if I'm working in a different tab in the same window -- I want the "shift+command+f" to just focus the already-open Search Editor.

**Is this possible?**

I've tried monkeying with "When" clauses on several of the Search Editor keybindings, and so far nothing is working. I've also looked through the Default Keybindings JSON and nothing jumps out at me as relevant.

Basically, I only ever want one Search Editor tab open, and any new searches should just append to the bottom. I believe this is how Sublime and Atom both do it and I've missed that functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just added to the Insiders' Build (so presumably in v1.48)

> Added `search.action.openEditor`, also available in command pallet[e] as
> "Open Search Editor" (as opposed to "New Search Editor" né "Open new
> Search Editor"), which will open an existing search editor if one
> exists, otherwise create a new one.

see [Reuse a single search editor tab per window](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100048) and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_48.md#search-editor.

Comment: Cool, I thought I remembered seeing something about this in the release notes. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Is there a place where all VS Code commands are documented along with any arguments they take? I'm not able to find such a list anywhere.